# I am creating a folder with a .txt file

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

in windows it works but when I test it on a ubuntu server the answer is [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'txts'
the code is:

```
def generarTxt(request,id):
    now = datetime.now()        
    fac= Factura.objects.get(pk=id)
    #Obtenemos los datos a guardar en el txt
    datos = request.GET['datos']
    #Creamos la ruta donde se van almacenar las carpetas
    os.makedirs('txts/'+str(request.session['usuario'][2])+'/out', exist_ok=True)        
    # Creamos el nombre del archivo 
    nombre = "datosFacturaNo_"+str(fac.numFactura)+'.txt'                
    #establecemos la ruta
    ruta = 'txts/'+str(request.session['usuario'][2])+'/out/'
    #Creamos y abrimos el archivo 
    f = open(ruta + nombre, 'w')        
    #Sobreescribimos el archivo
    f.write(datos.replace('_', '\n'))
    f.close()
```

Comment: In cases like this, you should double check the permissions of the folder in the Ubuntu server, since they might differ from those in the Windows server.

Comment: Note that on Linux, and Unix/Unix-like systems, they are "directories" and not the Windows-ism of "folders" which are not the same thing.